# Can I run Hadoop with Mac pro mid 2010 13inch processor?

Tags: hadoop, cloudera

My lap has 4gb ram, I want to upgrade to 8gb for Hadoop. But i am not sure that will work or not.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can start all Hadoop components I can imagine on such machine (even with 4GB, if you optimize well). I suggest using virtual evironments for such task (e.g. virtualbox).

But I am not sure your workload will survive or not (your jobs might be greedy).